# gtk_grid_new(); causing undefined reference error on compile

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, gtk

I was making a GUI in GTK and when i added a grid i got the error "undefined reference to "gtk_grid_new".

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtk/gtkfilechooser.h>

static GtkWidget *window , *textedit , *menu, *grid;

void destroy( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer   data ){
   gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",G_CALLBACK (destroy),NULL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300);
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);

    grid = gtk_grid_new();

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check if you are using gtk3. AFAIK gtkGrid is not available in gtk2, you will have to switch to gtk3 or use either gtkBox or gtkTable.

Comment: Thanks It worked Perfectly.